# Android app does not upgrade cleanly from the play store

Tags: android, trigger.io

We are using Trigger.io to package our sencha toucha app for the google play store. The problems comes when we upload an update to the play store. As soon as a user updates his app to a new version it stops working. It only works if you uninstall the previous version and do a fresh install. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: I've never used trigger.io, do they give you access to the XML manifest file? Can you post the new and old manifest files?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't give access to the XML manifest file. There is a config file in which we define versions

Comment: Post your config file, the new and old one (or the snippets of each one at least). Also, you may want to look through trigger.io 's knowledge base and file a bug report with them. This may be a problem with their packager . Even if you successfully solve your own problem, please let us know what you find (as your own answer).

Comment: What do you mean it stops working? Just wanted to get some clarification on what stops working means, like does now work at all, downloaded images don't show up etc.